# Process.getInputStream() seems to overwrite the output from the subprocess?

Tags: java, c++, asynchronous, process

I am trying to get the output of a program (written in C++) from Java by listening to the STDOUT/STDERR. When I run the C++ program through the console, I am able to properly see the expected output, and it works fine. However, when the program ends (I am basically looking for error codes), it spits out 3-4 lines almost immediately and then ends the output. When looking at the output from the console, this is fine. However, when listening to STDOUT from java, I am missing the final line from the output and lines seems to be "colliding", like this:

```
INFO: max_encoded_bytes = 76475 aERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 110 (Connection timed out).
```

When they should look like this:

```
INFO: max_encoded_bytes = 76475 at [line 939: program.cpp]
ERROR: RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect
FATAL: Error code 200
```

My code currently looks like this:

```
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);

processLock.lock();

logger.debug("Starting " + name + " process");

try {
    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    Future<?> outputFuture = executor.submit(() -> {
        br.lines().forEach(line -> {
            outputHandler.handleOutput(line);
        });
    });

    try {
        process.waitFor();
        outputFuture.get();
        logger.debug(name + " process completed naturally");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        logger.error("ExecutionException during " + name + " process: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.debug(name + " process interrupted");
        process.destroy();
    } finally {
        br.close();
        isr.close();
        is.close();
    }
catch (IOException e) { } //etc
```

Which, based on me looking at resources on the web, seems to be pretty standard for processing output.
I was reviewing some other SO questions that seemed similar, but I wasn't exactly sure since their situations are not identical to mine (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108750/java-output-from-process-buider-overwritten-when-using-bufferedreader) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832324/output-from-process-getinputstream-buffered-too-long)).

I have tried changing how I am reading from STDOUT through a whole bunch of different libs (removing BufferedStream, using InputStream directly, using ByteArrayOutputStream, changing buffer sizes to some absurdly large and small values, etc..). With the goal of matching the console output and printing out each line as it happens, what can I do to get the output that I think I should be getting?

Comment: Is it possible the error message goes to STDERR?

Comment: @jrtapsell, It might, which is why my code has `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` . However, when trying to test the stdout/stderr output, I piped the command into a text file by running `command &> test.txt` and it seems to not get the lines that I want at all. So, I think the issue might be with the C++ program. Unsure of it though.

Comment: It could be something to do with either the program not liking being piped, or something changing in the environment which is not the same

Comment: There is no reason to use an Executor here.   Just process all the lines before calling `process.waitFor()`.  This may or may not solve your problem, but simplifying the code will help narrow down the cause.  Also, *never* write an empty `catch` block—at the very least, put `e.printStackTrace();` in there, so you’ll know if something went wrong.

Comment: @VGR there's no empty catch block, it was just deleted for brevity. And, I need to process output as the program is running (concurrently), so that way I can see what's happening with the program. Isn't the proper way to do that through another thread?

Comment: ??? but you're calling `get()` immediately within the calling code -- how is any concurrency going on here? I'm with @VGR, your threading is not "threading".

Comment: While it is true that the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) states “There is no requirement that the process represented by a Process object execute asynchronously or concurrently with respect to the Java process that owns the Process object,” in practice the process executes asynchronously on every Windows, Unix, and Linux system I’ve encountered.  I suspect the statement was originally intended to cover Windows 9x runtimes.